# About setting up a VPN

Tags: networking, vpn

Do i need a dedicated server machine to run a VPN server or would it be ok if i used one of the working PC and a windows VPN client on it? I would expect at a time 10 clients to be connected and working on files not more than 5Mb. 
The upload speed is 5Mbps.

Comment: This question is likely to receive many differing answers. However, if connecting multiple clients simultaneously it would be easier to connect sites using a site-to-site VPN. Depending on budget there are a number of solutions available that are capable of this. There are routers available that have VPN server and client built-in (DrayTek Vigor range, for example, or you could change the firmware on a Netgear to use DD-WRT or Tomato that can do this) OR you could implement two servers (that have no user access) that can create the VPN for your offices (Microsoft Servers, for example)...

Answer (score 0):

You would probably be OK using a client machine, however inevitably with client machines, someone is going to reboot or shut down without asking and then all your VPN users get upset.  If you have an existing  server machine you would be better off.  Also check out OpenVPN and LogMeIn Hamachi as two good VPN softwares.  Hamachi is extremenly easy to set up, and OpenVPN is FOS.
Be prepared for user complaints about speed even with 5mbit.
Good luck.